# How to check an empty space (NULL) in double pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, memory-management, double-pointer

I am trying to use an 'if' condition to check whether a location for an object is empty or not. I am using double pointers for this. Please see the code below:

```
void show_room :: buy_car(int clmn, int row)
{
    int row = row;
    int clmn = clmn;
    string car_door_col;
    string temp1;
    float temp2;
    int temp3;
    int n=0, i;
    this->HBM = new show_room*[3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {               
        this->HBM[i] = new show_room[4];
    }

    for(int j=0; j<row; j++)
    {
        if(this->HBM[clmn][row] == NULL)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In this loop:

```
for(int j=0; j<row; j++)
{
    if(this->HBM[clmn][row] == NULL)
    {

    }
}
```

I am trying to check whether there is an object at [clmn][row] or not, and I am using NULL for this which is wrong. How am I supposed to implement this. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Why oh why are you doing this: `int row = row; int clmn = clmn;`

Comment: @meagar....i know this is wrong.....please ignore it..

Comment: FYI, in your check, you'll probably want to check j instead of row, since row doesn't change and you'll end up checking the same object every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already initialized the elements of `HBM` to 0, and you're remembering to reset them to 0 after deleting the objects they point to, you can simply do:

```
if(this->HBM[clmn][row]) {
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: Please consider this situatuion...there is something at HBM[0][2] and HBM[0][1] is empty. Now I am trying to implement something to check whether HBM[0][1] is empty or not. Please help.

Comment: @Spoilt So what's the problem exactly? Loop over `HBM` and test each element with an `if`, exactly as I've suggested. That will tell you whether the element is empty or not.

Comment: So where is the check? Wat you wrote will check the NULL condition or not?? Sorry that I am dumb but still please help..

Comment: @Spoilt The `if` *is* the check. That is what an `if` statement is. The body of the `if` will only execute if there is an object a `HBM[clmn][row]`. Otherwise, the condition evaluates to false and the body of the `if` is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `new show_room[4]` does not create four pointers to show_rooms, but four show_rooms in a row.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written it, you are simply constructing a two-dimensional array `show_room[3][4]` (with dynamic storage). Calling `new` means that every object gets constructed, so there are no "missing values" or "empty spaces".

When you say `HBM[i][j]`, precisely one of two things can happen:

- Either `i < 3` and `j < 4`, and you obtain a reference to a valid `show_room` object, or
- you incur undefined behaviour.

Nothing else can happen.